# Trouble in knowing when the cuda code gets compiled?

Tags: cuda, compiler-optimization, gpgpu, nvcc

I want to know, when the cuda code gets compiled? I mean is it possible to know the values of parameters of the cuda kernel which is given in the command line argument of host code run time? Is it possible to compile cuda code during run time of host code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical usage of the CUDA [runtime API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html), CUDA device code gets compiled when you pass a file containing CUDA device code to `nvcc`, the CUDA compiler driver engine.

CUDA device code can/will be compiled at run-time using either the [driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html) or using the CUDA [NVRTC](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html) mechanism.  There is documentation for each of these approaches, [CUDA sample codes](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples) for each of these approaches, and various questions here on the `cuda` SO tag for each.

When you use the CUDA driver API, the device source code you will present for compilation at run-time is in the form of PTX, a CUDA intermediate language.

For compilation of typical CUDA C++ device code at runtime, you would use the NVRTC mechanism.